# Access model bound item inside nested UpdatePanel

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel, repeater, model-binding, databound-controls

What is the correct method to access the data-bound item inside of a nested UpdatePanel?  I've recently discovered model binding and love the strongly-typed binding it offers, but I have a scattering of UpdatePanels throughout the page, and it seems to break access to the `Item` object. If the entire databound control is inside the UpdatePanel I have no problem.  This works:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="myRepeater" ItemType="Test.Person">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Item.Name %>' /><br />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

But if the UpdatePanel is inside the bound control, I no longer have access to `Item`.  This does not work:

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="myRepeater" ItemType="Test.Person">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Item.Name %>' /><br />  // <-- Problem line
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

> CS0103: The name 'Item' does not exist in the current context

I fumbled my way onto a clunky solution, which is this

```
((Person)GetDataItem()).Name
```

But I desperately hope this is not the best way of accomplishing the task.

Comment: You should place the UpdatePanel outside the Repeater. Not an UpdatePanel per RepeaterItem.

Comment: (Comment was too old to edit, I had to delete/recreate) @VDWWD I have items inside the repeater that I don't want updated. I discovered that images inside a _UpdatePanel_ cause screen flicker, so I only update the sections I need to.